# How can I access a variable from one Form in a different Form inside the same browser window?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to get the value of a string from a specific Form in a web based system my company uses.

When opened in the browser it consists of three Forms (not frames). A thin left side Menu Form, a top thin horizontal Banner Form, and the other 80% of the bottom right loads in the Form that I am building.

I need to be able to grab a string from the top banner Form named "mainForm".

This string is dynamically populated as it is not set and it just appears between the TD  tags. Also the TD element it resides in has no id or name, but it is the only instance of the class "userName".

I have tried several permutations trying to access this class/string combo.

Examples of what I have tried:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName("userName")
    document.querySelector('form[name="mainForm"] .userName').innterHTML
    document.getElementsByClassName("userName")[0].innerText
    document.mainForm.querySelector('.userName').innerText
    document.forms.mainForm.getElementsByClassName('userName')
    mainForm.getElementsByClassName("userName")
    window.form["mainForm"].getElementsByClassName("userName")
    document.form["mainForm"].getElementsByClassName("userName")
    window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName("userName")
```

```
<!--Excerpts of code-->

    <form name="mainForm" style="margin: 0px;" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td align="right" class="userName" nowrap="">Target Text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
        <button type="button" id="btnLog" name="btnLog" onclick="getLog()">Get 
        Log</button>
    </form>

    function getLog() {
        var elementLog = document.getElementsByClassName("userName");
        var log = elementLog.textContent;
        alert(log);
    }
```

I expect the alert(log) to return the string value of the userName class.

What actually happens is either the alert triggers and says "undefined" or console errors of unable to get property of undefined or null reference.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Try to check for length then request index 0. Also try to use `.value` for input.value instead of `.textContent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `innerHTML` (and not `innterHTML`):

```js
function getLog() {
  var elementLog = document.getElementsByClassName("userName")[0];
  var log = elementLog.innerHTML;
  console.log(log);
}
```

```html
<!--Excerpts of code-->

    <form name="mainForm" style="margin: 0px;" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td align="right" class="userName" nowrap="">Target Text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
        <button type="button" id="btnLog" name="btnLog" onclick="getLog()">Get 
        Log</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Whoops, yeah that was a typo. So there must be something else going on here as that still gives an "unable to get property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference. When I look at the developer console I see that my form is loaded into a larger file called view.cfm and the userName string I am trying to access is within another file called index.cfm?

Comment: Oh, it seems you are dealing with partial views?

Comment: Possibly, from what I can see in the developer console I don't see any  partial related methods being utilized. However the developers of this system also made custom "frames" in CSS/HTML instead of what is traditionally considered a frame so I do not know if these developers follow typical conventions.

Comment: Even though this doesn't work for the system I am utilizing, I am accepting this comment as the answer because it works for the problem that I have stated on this post as seen in the above code snippet in case anyone else is looking for that particular question..